# Affine open with irreducible complement

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, schemes

Let $X$ be an integral Noetherian separated scheme. Under what conditions can we find a non-empty affine open in $X$ whose complement is irreducible?

Comment: Meta discussion here:  https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/4200/flood-of-new-users

Answer (score 1):

An (almost) obvious sufficient condition is that $X$ is projective.

In fact, take a very ample line bundle $\mathcal{H}$ on $X$. Then the general element $H$ in the complete linear system $|\mathcal{H}|$ is irreducible because, by a version of Bertini theorem, a reducible linear system without fixed parts is necessarily composed with a pencil, in particular, it cannot be very ample (see [O. Zariski, *Algebraic surfaces*, page 26]).

Now $X-H$ is the non-empty, open affine subset you are looking for.

**Remark 1.** The argument works for geometrically irreducible projective schemes over any field (included finite fields, see the comments).

**Remark 2.** If $X$ is quasi-projective then the same argument applies, after passing to a projective closure $\bar{X}$ of $X$.

Comment: here "projective" means "projective over an algebraically closed field", right?

Comment: There are versions of Bertini's theorem working even over *finite* fields (under the assumption that $X$ is *geometrically irreducible*, i.e., irreducible over any field extension of the base field). See https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/87ee/1b77556baddf711fba956c78bfb6703d2b18.pdf

Comment: but I mean the question does not specify the base (the scheme could be even $\mathrm{Spec}\,\mathbb{Z}$) so you probably could specifically say that in the answer.

Comment: "Over a field" is enough. Classical Bertini works for infinite fields, and the case of finite fields is addressed by the link I posted in the comment above. Over non-algebraically closed fields, $X$ must be geometrically irreducible.